# radius of convergence for taylor series in mathematica

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

Assume we have the following series:

```
 1 - x^2/6 + x^4/120 - x^6/5040 + x^8/362880
```

Can I evaluate the radius of convergence for both of them? in Mathematica?

In general how can evaluate the radius of convergence is |an/an+1| for large n for any series in mathematica?

Comment: I believe one way to *estimate* the radius of convergence is $|a_{n}/a_{n+1}|$ for large $n$.  In this case, that limit goes to infinity, which would imply an infinite radius of convergence (which is true here, since I'm assuming that's the power series for $e^x$).

Comment: Dear, yes I want to evaluate the radius of convergence is |an/an+1| for large n, for any series , what shall use in mathematica?

Comment: In the new edit, you now have the first few terms of the Taylor series of cosine instead of the Taylor series for the exponential, but these two power series are intimately related to each other, and anyway, the first method I outlined below will work because we have a closed form for the coefficients of that entire series. I'm beginning to suspect a little that you need to read up a little on series, radius of convergence, Taylor series, and such.

Comment: Thanks march do you have some good book or lecture notes for that!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One can either use `SumConvergence` or `Sum` with `GenerateConditions -> True` (thanks to a comment by [Artes](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/184/artes)). As an example:

```
Sum[Cos[n] x^n, {n, 1, Infinity}, VerifyConvergence -> True, GenerateConditions -> True]
ConditionalExpression[-((x (1 + E^(2 I) - 2 E^I x))/(2 (E^I - x) (-1 + E^I x))), x != E^I && E^I x != 1 && Abs[x] < 1]
```

Unfortunately, `SumConvergence` doesn't seem to work:

```
SumConvergence[Cos[n] x^n, n]
SumConvergence[Cos[n] x^n, n, Assumptions -> -1 < x < 1]
SumConvergence[Cos[n] x^n, n, Method -> "RatioTest"]
SumConvergence[Cos[n] x^n, n, Method -> "RootTest"]
SumConvergence[Cos[n] x^n, n, Method -> "RaabeTest"]
SumConvergence[Cos[n] x^n, n, Method -> "IntegralTest"]
```

Below, I work through some of the theory and do this also numerically.

---

The radius of convergence $R$ is given by
$$
\frac{1}{R} = \lim_{n\to\infty}\sup(\sqrt[n]{|a_n|})
$$
In this case, the coefficients are $\frac{1}{n!}$, which is a monotonically decreasing sequence, and so for our case, this becomes
$$
\frac{1}{R} = \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n!}
$$
Using *Mathematica*,

```
Limit[1/Factorial[n], n -> ∞]
(* 0 *)
```

and hence the radius of convergence is infinity, as it should be for the Taylor series of the exponential function.

---

Here is an example with a more complicated function.  Consider the series
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\cos(n)x^n.
$$
In *Mathematica*, we get

```
Sum[Cos[n] x^n, {n, 1, \[Infinity]}] // ExpToTrig;
(Numerator@% Conjugate@Denominator@% // ComplexExpand)/( Denominator@% Conjugate@Denominator@% // ComplexExpand) // Simplify
(* (x (-x + Cos[1]))/(1 + x^2 - 2 x Cos[1]) *)
```

Plotting this function, we get

```
Plot[{(x (-x + Cos[1]))/(1 + x^2 - 2 x Cos[1]), Sum[Cos[n] x^n, {n, 1, 50}]}, {x, -1.01, 1.01}]
```

[image]

which suggests that the radius of convergence is 1.  We can verify this numerically in the following way. Make a table of values of the coefficients:

```
tbl = Table[(N@Abs[Cos[n]])^(1/n), {n, 1, 10000}];
```

Then compute the maxima of successively larger subsets of the values and plot them:

```
Table[Max[tbl[[;; kk]]], {kk, 1, 10000}] // ListPlot
```

[image]

That sure appears to be equal to one!

Comment: Thank you march, since it simple coefficients you can find it but for complicate series what shall we do for:      0.1 + 0.397953 t + 0.592849 t^2 + 0.588719 t^3 + 0.438295 t^4 + 
 0.260863 t^5 + 0.129195 t^6

Comment: @user62716. Perhaps give an example of a more complicated series and edit your OP with your true question!

Comment: I modified the question, I want general way for any series, can we do it?

Comment: But those aren't series, those are just polynomials. Unless you have a general expression for the (infinite number of) coefficients, then all you have are polynomials, and so the radius of convergence is of course always infinite.

Comment: @user62716 What you are looking form is just `SumConvergence`, it has options where one can use e.g. `"IntegralTest", "RaabeTest","RatioTest"`, however there is no tool which can predict another coefficient of a series you have in mind.

Comment: @Artes. I'd forgotten about that one. Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to work for the example I've written up in my edited answer!

Comment: @Artes. Well, sure! But since `SumConvergence` doesn't work, we can't get the radius of convergence *directly* or analytically. Hence my answer.  (Am I missing something?)

Comment: @march `Sum[Cos[n] x^n, {n, 1, Infinity}, VerifyConvergence -> True, 
 GenerateConditions -> True]`

Comment: @Artes.  Okay!  Thank you! I haven't played much with the analytic `Sum` features in *Mathematica*. It's irritating that I couldn't get `SumConvergence` to make this work. So it goes. Of course, it seems to me that the OP wasn't really clear on what they wanted anyway.

Comment: Dear march, the last line Table[Max[tbl[[;; kk]]], {kk, 1, 10000}] // ListPlot is not work I don't know why?

Comment: @user62716. Because in the definition of `tbl`, there is an `a[n]` rather than `Cos[n]`, left over from how I coded it in my copy of Mathematica. I have fixed it, and you should fix your definition of `tbl` and rerun the code.

Comment: Thanks it works now!!! can you suggest some good book or lecture notes for  series, radius of convergence, Taylor series

Comment: @user62716. I mean, that material is standard fare for undergraduate mathematics courses. I expect that it would be in a lot of standard undergraduate calculus texts.

Comment: Thank you march..