# Converges or diverges?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, bugs

Studying the behavior of the series $$ \sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \left(1-\frac{\log (n)}{n}\right)^{2 n}$$,
I try in 12.3.1 on Windows 10

```
SumConvergence[(1 - Log[n]/n)^(2 n), n]
```

> `False`

, but

```
SumConvergence[(1 - Log[n]/n)^(2 n), n, Method -> "RaabeTest"]
```

> `True`

The result of

```
NSum[(1 - Log[n]/n)^(2 n), {n, 1, Infinity}]
```

> `1.33193*10^244`

confirms the divergence and the results of

```
NSum[(1 - Log[n]/n)^(2 n), {n, 1, Infinity}, WorkingPrecision -> 30]
```

> `1.407104427435176587354`

and

```
Series[(1 - Log[n]/n)^(2 n), {n, Infinity, 3}]
```

> `(1/n)^2-Log[n]^2/n^3+O(1/n)^4`

stand for the convergence.

What should I trust?

Comment: The option `Method->"IntegralTest"`  should correctly work here in view of `AsymptoticEqual[(1 - Log[n]/n)^(2 n), 1/n^2, n -> Infinity]` which answers `True`, but fails.

Comment: You can just plot the sum-terms with increasing `n` and see that the curve goes to zero.

Comment: I added a new sequence to the OEIS, see https://oeis.org/A354450. To calculate the more accurate value of this sum, it was more appropriate to use Maple instead of Mathematica. `Series[(1 - Log[n]/n)^(2*n), {n, Infinity, 30}]` is for many hours. In Maple, the expansion of 100 terms is done almost immediately.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Do the Raabe test by hand:

```
b[n_] = (1 - Log[n]/n)^(2 n);

Limit[n (b[n]/b[n + 1] - 1), n -> Infinity]
(* 2 *)
```

converges.

Comment: You incorrectly apply the Raabe's test (see [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_test) for info). You wrote "If the Raabe test gives a result >1 it indicates that the series diverges" which is not true.

Comment: You are right, it is the other way round. >1 means convergence. I corrected my answer.

Answer (score 6):

This looks like a horrible bug present in 12.3.1 (still happens on 13.0.1) (indeed **due to "SumConvergence uses pre V11.2 Limit" and it is used for DivergenceTest**). First of all even if on this limit Raabe test Method does work there is worse example here: [Why doesn't Mathematica provide an answer while Wolfram|Alpha does, concerning a series convergence?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/224072/why-doesnt-mathematica-provide-an-answer-while-wolframalpha-does-concerning-a#comment645719_224072)
**I suppose DivergenceTest has higher priority (remember it is only meaningful for False, for True it means nothing).**
Or the problem there is that Raabe is done on nonnegative series and it somehow fails to check it.
So:

```
a[n_] := (1 - Log[n]/n)^(2 n);
SumConvergence[a[n], n, Method -> Automatic] (* False, bug: does not TRY Raabe *)
SumConvergence[a[n], n, Method -> "RaabeTest"] (* True, NICE. It is 2. *)
SumConvergence[a[n], n, Method -> "RatioTest"] (* Error *)
SumConvergence[a[n], n, Method -> "RootTest"] (* Error *)
SumConvergence[a[n], n, Method -> "DivergenceTest"] (* False, a bug! *)
SumConvergence[a[n], n, Method -> "IntegralTest"] (* Fails, infinite loop  bug!! *)
```

For DivergenceTest see https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/163389/82985
Now, they broke IntegralTest long time ago, see [SumConvergence difficulty](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/140056/sumconvergence-difficulty/163329#163329) first workaround on 1- Cos[Pi/n] there does not help this case though, it errors out after some time but FreeQ idea and myLCT do work, WOW. FreeQ does not work on (1 - Log[n]/n)^(2 n) though by myLCT does. So...

Now, indeed both Raabe test by hand and next level of it (in the series of Kummer's tests), Bertrand test (strange it is not one of Methods, WTF, one can even use Extended Betrand that is continuation further of that):

```
b[n_] = (1 - Log[n]/n)^(2 n);

Limit[Log[n] (n (b[n]/b[n + 1] - 1) - 1), n -> Infinity] (* prints Infinity, so convergent *)
```

Other example is worse. It is actually quite interesting, see: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2830362/sum-limitsn-1-infty1-cos-frac-pin-convergence-proof?noredirect=1&lq=1 and related questions.

```
a[n_] := 1 - Cos[Pi/n];
SumConvergence[a[n], n, Method -> Automatic] (* error *)
SumConvergence[a[n], n, Method -> "RaabeTest"] (* error *)
SumConvergence[a[n], n, Method -> "RatioTest"] (* error *)
SumConvergence[a[n], n, Method -> "RootTest"] (* error *)
SumConvergence[a[n], n, Method -> "DivergenceTest"] (* true, so useless *)
SumConvergence[a[n], n, Method -> "IntegralTest"] (* error *)
```

Raabe by hand again prints 2 while Betrand's prints Infinity. So converges.

```
b[n_] = 1 - Cos[Pi/n];

Limit[Log[n] (n (b[n]/b[n + 1] - 1) - 1), n -> Infinity] (* Infinity *)
```

Now I would not say this Raabe approach is always perfect. Try:

```
b[n_] = Abs[Sin[n]]^n/n;

Limit[n (b[n]/b[n + 1] - 1), n -> Infinity] (* Infinite loop *)
```

Comment: +1. Many thanks from me to you for your investigation.

Comment: I think that it somehow fails to see it is positive sequence, since that is a requirement for Raabe test. Since some n of course. I mean you cannot get anything after that wrong and it does work by hand.

Comment: As I understand it, the comparison test is out of scope of `SumConvergence`.

Comment: Raabe, Bertrand and Dalamber all require positive terms. It fails to check that on 1 - Cos[Pi/n], I suppose.

Comment: Also myLCT only works for IntegralTest for (1 - Log[n]/n)^(2 n), FreeQ example does not work (and loops for a long time too).

Comment: I think I know what the bug is. It uses DivergenceTest that is only good if it is False, for True it means nothing. Now, it is undocumented and here it fails. For the other example it is True so the result is unevaluated. It looks like Raabe test has less priority than that of DivergenceTest. YES! Also, there is this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2830362/sum-limitsn-1-infty1-cos-frac-pin-convergence-proof?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: I opened a giant thread on wolfram community. https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2419493

Comment: The bug is indeed "SumConvergence uses pre V11.2 Limit" as used in DivergenceTest. Nice.

Comment: The discussion should belong to calculus-and-analysis group, not to discrete math group. Also sense of sharing this theme at community.wolfram.com  is unclear to me.

Comment: devs should be reading it, and I was right. :)

Comment: There are more tools (e.g. $\LaTeX$) and more users and more questions here.

Answer (score 4):

`SumConvergence` uses pre V11.2 `Limit`, which evaluates to the wrong answer below. This makes `SumConvergence` think the summand fails the divergence test and hence returns `False`.

Compare:

```
Asymptotics`ClassicLimit[(1 - Log[n]/n)^(2 n), n -> ∞, Assumptions -> n ∈ Integers]
```

> ```
> 1
> ```

```
Limit[(1 - Log[n]/n)^(2 n), n -> ∞, Assumptions -> n ∈ Integers]
```

> ```
> 0
> ```

Swapping definitions fixes the issue:

```
Block[{Asymptotics`ClassicLimit = Limit},
  SumConvergence[u[n], n]
]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

Comment: Can you kindly elaborate your post to make it understandable? TIA.

Comment: The condition $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=0$ is only a necessary condition for the convergence of a series. There are both convergent series and divergent series which satisfy it.

Comment: ‘SumConvergence’ uses that ‘ClassicLimit’ function instead of ‘Limit’. ‘ClassicLimit’ is returning 1 for that limit and so ‘SumConvergence’ thinks the sum is divergent. Forcing ‘SumConvergence’ to use ‘Limit’ instead of ‘ClassicLimit’ fixes this issue.

Comment: Thank you. BTW, Asymptotics ` ClassicLimit[(1 - Log[n]/n)^(2 n), n -> \[Infinity]] returns `0`. Indeed,  the documentation says `SumConvergence` was not  updated since 2010.

Comment: Do you have any idea what causes RaabeTest to fail for 1 - Cos[Pi/n]? Limit hack does not work there. I think it cannot confirm it is positive sequence, since that is needed for Raabe.

Comment: Another example that this hack works on is Cos[n] x^n. It returns false... See https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/215363/82985

Comment: Can we have a bug header for this and a separate bug for RaabeTest bug https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/224072/82985?

Comment: I would imagine so. Though I don't know the prerequisites to allow the tag.

Comment: BTW, you cannot use Assumptions on -> variable. It prints a warning even in 13.1 on Limit[(1 - Log[n]/n)^(2 n), n -> ∞, Assumptions -> n ∈ Integers]. That only works on ClassicLimit, but even then DiscreteLimit is better, but not always, see https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/261428/82985

Comment: In 13.2 https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/261428/82985 is fixed, so you can now IMHO replace ClassicLimit with  DiscreteLimit[(1 - Log[n]/n)^(2 n), n -> \\[Infinity]]

Answer (score 2):

Not a real answer, but rather a recommendation to ask a mathematician in this case (e.g., at https://math.stackexchange.com/). Mathematica does not seem to provide a definite answer. In the methods you have several options

```
a[n_] := (1 - Log[n]/n)^(2 n)
SumConvergence[a[n], n, Method -> Automatic]
SumConvergence[a[n], n, Method -> "RaabeTest"]
SumConvergence[a[n], n, Method -> "RatioTest"]
SumConvergence[a[n], n, Method -> "RootTest"]
```

> False

> True

I suppose the answers depend on the considered test. RatioTest and RootTest return nothing. Manual investigation of the ratio and root test yields

```
temp = FullSimplify[Abs[a[n + 1]/a[n]], n > 0];
Limit[temp, n -> Infinity]
temp = FullSimplify[Abs[a[n]]^(1/n), n > 0];
Limit[temp, n -> Infinity]
```

> 1

> 1

meaning that both of these test can NOT give an answer, see, e.g., [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergent_series). Try asking in https://math.stackexchange.com/. This question could also be moved there.

Comment: Disagree. This is a Mathematica question with  the codes and results.  Unfortunately, Mathematica produces some wrong results in this case without any warnings.. Thank you anyway for your personal opinion.

Comment: BTW, I don't find any post tugged by `calculus-and-analysis` in your [profile](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/24710/mauricio-fernández?tab=topactivity).

Comment: You omitted `Method->"IntegralTest"` which should correctly work here, but fails, in your above direction. This does not make a good impression.

Comment: Also how about `NSum`?